# Access variables in functions of imported classes

Tags: python, python-2.7, function, local-variables

I have an imported module in my code. The module contains a function defined in it. The function does not return any value. In my code, I want to access a variable declared in that function. Is there a way to do it?

**Edit:**
So, there is a module inside an OSS which is generating a speech sequence. But the speech sequence variable is not global, neither the function returns the speech sequence. I want to access the speech sequence in my addon.

Comment: that sounds like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378). what are you trying to achieve? please provide a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)
that reproduces your problem.

Comment: A variable in that function's scope? Without any reference to the module or your code it's hard to tell, but you ought not be able to access variables defined in a function's scope from where you're calling it.

Comment: Edited, with the problem.

Comment: does the function put its results in one of the mutable arguments? otherwise: what does it do? why is it there?

Comment: Are you allowed to run the function code in the process? Anyway, why do you need this functionality? Usually in a piece of (_3rdParty_) code, things are as they are because whoever wrote that code meant them to be as such :).

Answer (score 0):

If your function looks like this:

```
def function():
    ...
    my_variable = "foo"
```

Then you can add a parameter that would force that variable to be returned along with anything that is being returned. So the function would look like this.

```
def function(get_variable=False):
    ...
    return_variable = "bar"
    my_variable = "foo"
    if get_variable:
        return (my_variable, return_variable)
    else:
        return return_variable
```

And then access it like this:

```
import module


my_variable, return_variable = module.function(get_variable=True)
```

You don't need this sort of hack if your function doesn't return anything at all. Just make it return the variable you want and assign it to something inside your main code's scope.

Comment: I already know it. But the thing, as I mentioned is, that this is an open source software and I building an addon for it cant make changes for the time being. Hence, this hack wont possibly work?

Comment: I don't think there is any other way of achieving this.. You can still edit the source to fit your needs though..

Comment: I could help you out if you'd like, just tell me which module, function and variable you want :)

Comment: Glad you said! here is the git link: https://github.com/nvaccess/nvda. The module is speech.py in source directory of the repository. Inside it, is the function named `speakTextInfo` which generates a speechSequence. I want to use that in my code.

Comment: Have you installed this module from pip, or what?

Comment: Nope, normal cloning. I've put it in comment since you were asking about the module. You can't commit changes to it. While building addons, its required for reference.

Comment: Then just be cloning this http://github.com/StamKaly/nvda instead of the original one, the sequence is returned in the function, but take into consideration it might be empty!

Comment: And how do you suppose it to work? Unless and until your commit is taken in by the organisation, it's not reflected in the screenreader. So merely committing to repo doesn't do the work!

Comment: That is unless you are building it on your own. If you do a full build, my changes must work.

Comment: Can you tell me though some things, because I don't really know how `nvda` works or how you are using it. What are using the repo for, eg as I can see there's a section `Running the Source Code` in `readme`, is that what you are doing? If so, how are you intergrating this module inside your code. Sorry, but I can't really help you if I don't have a good context..

Comment: It has got nothing to do with the repo. There is a separate file which needs to be created and installed in the Manage Addon option, while running NVDA. The repo is merely to study whats actually happening. You can refer to this addon for reference: https://github.com/tspivey/speakPasswords

Comment: Is that file contained in the repo?

Comment: Nope. That's the thing to notice. When you run `scons source` while in your addon file, an addon file is generated and this has to be installed in the Manage Addons option, while running nvda

Comment: How are you starting NVDA, are you using the launcher in the repo?

Comment: Ok, I guess I can make my changes work by doing a binary build. I have to go now though, will be back in a couple of hours :)